# Hide div when browser menu is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide content in div when my webpage window is not active. I have tis code in jQuery:

```
$(window).blur(function(){
    $("#context").hide();
});

$(window).focus(function(){
    $("#context").show();
});
```

It works fine but if open browser menu(menu containing new tab, history... options), context doesn't hide. Is there any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: try to combine blue with mouseout event. If your mouse is not in the windows region hide the "context".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. There is no browser API for detecting interaction with native elements. The closest you're going to be able to get is to watch for the cursor leaving the window near the part of the browser frame that contains the menu handle. However, since each browser places this menu in a different location, you're going to end up getting into a quaqmire of UA detection, timers, and mousemove events to get it right.

Comment: In another word, a coding nightmare. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").mouseleave(function(){
    $( "#context" ).hide();  
  });
});
```

Comment: This will effectively tell you when the mouse has left the body element, however since the body element can be of any size, it doesn't effectively tell you if the the mouse has hit the 'menu button' requested by OP, or even if the mouse has left the browser frame.